# How do I create while loop the swaps all lower case letters in. string to upper case and vicevera?

Tags: input, while-loop, swap, uppercase, lowercase

```
def swap_case(string):
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(string):
        if string[pos].isupper():
            return string[pos].lower()
        else:
            return string[pos].upper()
        pos = pos + 1

print(swap_case('Hello'))
```

This what I've attempted however it only converts the first letter and no other letters within the inputed string, is anyone able to help me understand how to correctly write this code. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Hey, `return` exits the function immediately. If you want to change the character in the string you need to use assignment as `string[pos] = string[pos].lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

The bug in your code is that the `return` statement is too soon after the first iteration, that's why only the first letter is returned.

The use of 'string' as a variable is discouraged because it is a reserved word, for example

```
import string
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

I have also converted the string s to a list `['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, so that each letter can be iterated through to check/change the case.

Finally the converted list can be returned with `''.join(s)`

```
def swap_case(s):
    pos = 0
    s = list(s)
    while pos < len(s):
        if s[pos].isupper():
            s[pos] = s[pos].lower()
        else:
            s[pos] = s[pos].upper()
        pos = pos + 1
    return ''.join(s)

print(swap_case('Hello'))
```

Output

```
hELLO
```

Another way is to use list comprehension, same output as above

```
def swap_case(s):
    return ''.join([x.lower() if x.isupper() else x.upper() for x in list(s)])

print(swap_case('Hello'))
```

Comment: list comprehension is neat, and it has the same output as the long code above